# javascript function saying it doesn't exist when it does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function and then pass the value of the button clicked to that function but even though the function does exist its saying it doesn't and im not sure why. Basically I need to call the powerOn() function when the power on button is clicked and then return the status messages. All I need to know is why it won't call the function so I can make sure I get the basic response.

Also I'm not entirely sure why sortable returns a console error when im following the documentation on http://github.hubspot.com/sortable/api/options/:

```
ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined vmstatus:123
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5375
TypeError: powerOn is not a function
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                $('#table-repeat-data').remove();
                                setInterval(update, 1000);  
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                $('#table_name').append("<table class='table' id='table-repeat-data' data-sortable><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");

                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn()" class="btn btn-primary" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power On</button>';
                                    var powerOff = '<button type="button" name="PowerOff" id="powerOff" class="btn btn-danger" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power Off</button>';
                                    var resetVM = '<button type="button" name="ResetVM"  id="ResetVM" class="btn btn-warning" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">ResetVM</button>';
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '1">' + on + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM + '</td></tr>');
                                    }else{
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '">' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '1">' + off + '</td><td id="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">' + powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM + '</td></tr>');
                                    }
                                }


                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });
                    return false;
            });              
        });

function update(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn()" class="btn btn-primary" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power On</button>';
                                    var powerOff = '<button type="button" name="PowerOff" id="powerOff" class="btn btn-danger" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power Off</button>';
                                    var resetVM = '<button type="button" name="ResetVM" id="ResetVM" class="btn btn-warning" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">ResetVM</button>';
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){           
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][2] + '1';
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = on;
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).innerHTML = powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM;
                                    }else{
                                        var get_element_id = json.vmlist[index][2] + '1';                                   
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][0]).innerHTML = json.vmlist[index][0];
                                        document.getElementById(get_element_id).innerHTML = off;
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).innerHTML = powerOn + ' ' + powerOff + ' ' + resetVM;
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });

}        

function powerOn() {
                    console.log('powerOn');
                    console.log(this.val());
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_vm : $(this).val(),
                            username : '{{user_name}}',
                            ip_address: '{{ip}}',
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                console.log(json.server_response);
                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });
   }

Sortable.init();
var dataTable;
dataTable = document.querySelector('#table-repeat-data');
Sortable.initTable(dataTable);  

</script>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the issue. We need to be able to reproduce your problem in order to help troubleshoot.

Comment: You can't use jsfiddle because it talks to django to get the information and makes the dynamic data based on a json list returned from django. The django code is irrelevant. The only relevant code is posted. That is the entire javascript code. @showdev

Comment: I believe the issue has to do with the fact that I dynamically create the button code that calls onClick='powerOn()'

Comment: I suggest creating a dummy django response for debugging. Otherwise, the problem is difficult/impossible to reproduce. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: <script src="{% static 'sortable.js' %}"></script> its not on there because there is no error message in the console saying it can't find it.

Comment: What happen if you give your function a slightly different name - e.g. `function onPowerOn1()` ?

Comment: I don't know why sortable isn't working though because I know its loading it I can see it in the console debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the name of your function, or changing the name of your variable of the same name.  It's possible that it is getting confused as to which one you actually mean due to scope.

```
var powerOn = '<button type="button" name="PowerOn" id="powerOn" onClick="powerOn()" class="btn btn-primary" value="' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '">Power On</button>';

function powerOn() {...}
```

which one is `powerOn`?  They both are.  It's possible that your function is later overridden to a string value and then it is no longer valid to try and call it like it was a function.

Comment: Yea I did that and it worked, I didn't notice I named it the same thank you.